# Invalid property identifier character: ‘. Path '', line 1, position 1 when parsing json string to object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting Invalid property identifier character: ‘. Path '', line 1, position 1 while parsing json string to object.
My Json string look like this

```
{‘name’ : ‘Account’ , ‘placeholder’ : ‘Enter Accountant Name’ , ‘label’ : ‘Account Name’ , ‘type’ : ‘string’ , ‘mode’: ‘multiline’}
```

and the class look like this

```
public class TemplateModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public string placeholder { get; set; }

    public string label { get; set; }

    public string mode { get; set; } = "single";
}
```

I am getting error in this line.

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(d);

I have checked the Newtonsoft.Json doucument and found a example when i copy the example and replace with my keys and static values. It works fine. string from example look like this.

```
       var c= @"{'name': 'james@example.com', 'type': 'string', 'label': 'Name', 'placeholder':'Enter Name', 'mode': 'multiline'}";
```

When i validate my json string in json validator online it validated properly except it replace my ' ' to " " but i have used ' ' because it  is used like this in Newtonsoft.Json example.

I am reading my json string template from word file. My json looks like this in text visulazar.

https://ibb.co/XjWrmS7

Please help.

I created this issue in fiddle, Please check  https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTma0B

Comment: Your first JSON string looks like it has smart-quote characters instead of "normal" quotes. E.g., you have ‘ and ’, but both of them should be the ' character.

Comment: I have tried your sample and got no error. https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCtYTv

Comment: @JoeSewell I have tried with "normal" quotes and '  ' both but still having same issue. The reason of using ' '  is because ' ' mentioned in Newtonsoft.Json. Also when i use static json string with ' ' works fine.

Comment: @MuzafferGalata when i use static string like you have used in example it works fine. I get my string by reading a word file and then using regex to fetch this particular pattern. My dynamic json string look like this {‘name’ : ‘Account’ , ‘placeholder’ : ‘Enter Accountant Name’ , ‘label’ : ‘Account Name’ , ‘type’ : ‘string’ , ‘mode’: ‘multiline’}

Comment: Any chance to create just a little fiddle sample?

Comment: @MuzafferGalata Please check https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTma0B    I have console both the strings i am getting but object not creating

Comment: Did you check your string ss? `{‘name’ : ‘Account' , ‘placeholder’ : ‘Enter Accountant Name’, ‘label’ : ‘Account Name’ , ‘type’ : ‘string’ , ‘mode’: ‘multiline’}
{‘name’ : ‘Account’ , ‘placeholder’ : ‘Enter Accountant Name’ , ‘label’ : ‘Account Name’ , ‘type’ : ‘string’ , ‘mode’: ‘multiline’}` This is not a valid TemplateModel object.

Comment: @MuzafferGalata why ? I just also noticed one thing that the smart-quotes around my keys and values are not actually smart-qoute if i replace this with smart-quote. it works iin js fiddle. I am reading string from word so i think it is converting quote to something else. Are you pointing the same thing ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are having smart quotes instead of the normal quotes.

I tried the following with normal quotes on the server side

```
{
   "name":"Account",
   "placeholder":"Enter Accountant Name",
   "label":"Account Name",
   "type":"string",
   "mode":"multiline"
}
```

and this works fine.

Can you verify by changing the quotes if that works for you?

Comment: Not working. Already  tried  this with both smart quotes and normal quotes but same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was an issue with the quotes. Accidentally, I have not put quotes at the start & at the end of the parameter I had double quotes. Removing the double quotes at the end fixed the issue.

Either you have to put double quotes on both sides or don't put them at both sides of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, because there was issue in AppSettings.json file.

"AllowedHosts": "*",
----> Some invalid statement here was causing the issue.